# Passport simple authentification with hashed password on an API

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I try to authentificate on a /login route with passport, I give an email, and a password (already stored in the database -email + hashed password with bcrypt). However, when I try to authentificate, my code never go into the passport.use...

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

const db = require("../config/database");

/* Route methods */
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  console.log("It will be displayed");

  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(function(email, password, done) {
      console.log("It won't");
      db.User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect email." });
        }

        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.dataValues.password)) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password." });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    })
  );
};
```

Furthermore, I create an API, and I'm wondering how authentificate someone (with session) with a REST API. Do I have to send on a endpoint the email and the password, then I create a session ? Thank you if you have any ressources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have only declared the actual `Strategy` but you'll need to create a separate route where you will authenticate the user using this local strategy with `passport.authenticate`.

Take a look at the example app I've created: https://github.com/BCooperA/express-authentication-starter-api

In `config/passport.js` I've created the actual `Strategy`:

```
const passport         = require('passport')
    , mongoose         = require('mongoose')
    , User             = mongoose.model('User')
    , LocalStrategy    = require('passport-local').Strategy;

/**
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Local authentication strategy (email, password)
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'user[email]', passwordField: 'user[password]' },
    function(email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {
            if(err)
                return done(err);

            // incorrect credentials
            if (!user || !user.validPassword(password) || user.password === '') {
                return done(null, false, { errors: [{ msg: "Incorrect credentials" }] });
            }

            // inactive account
            if(user.activation_token !== '' || user.active === 0) {
                // account is not activated
                return done(null, false, { errors: [{ msg: "Inactive account" }] });
            }

            // all good
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
```

In addition, I've also created a separate `POST` route for signing in users locally where I'm using `passport.authenticate`.

In `routes/auth.routes.js`:

```
const router          = require('express').Router()
    , mongoose        = require('mongoose')
    , User            = mongoose.model('User')
    , passport        = require('passport');

/**
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Local Authentication
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Authenticates user using Local Strategy by Passport
 */
router.post('/signin', function(req, res, next) {

    if(req.body.user.email === '' || req.body.user.password === '')
    // overrides passports own error handler
        return res.status(422).json({errors: [{ msg: 'Missing credentials'}]});

    passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, function(err, user, info) {
        if(err)
            return next(err);

        if(user) {
            // generate JSON web token to user
            user.token = user.generateJWT();

            // return user object
            return res.status(200).json({ user: user.toAuthJSON() });
        } else {
            // return any errors
            return res.status(422).json(info);
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Sorry, it was not really clear, but I do not want to create a JWT. I want to handle real session.